# Why is the planet Lola Sayu so damaged?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

The wikis just say it's "sulphurous and cracked" which sounds like a huge understatement.  Is there any backstory to this rather damaged planet?

[image: round purple planet, the bottom half of which looks cracked and yellow]

Comment: Almost looks like Peragus after the gas explosion

Comment: I've checked all the usual suspects and I can't find anything that explains why it's cracked.

Comment: For damage of that sort, I'd venture that the most probable cause is one of the many ancient Sith superweapons powered by giant kyber crystals

Comment: The exogorths were hungry that day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It hasn't been established.

I [asked](https://twitter.com/The_Rogue_Jedi/status/733102077229051904) [Leland Chee](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Leland_Chee), a member of [the Lucasfilm Story Group](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lucasfilm_Story_Group) and the maintainer of [the official Holocron Database](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Holocron_continuity_database), your question.

[image: Tweet]

He [responded](https://twitter.com/HolocronKeeper/status/733140666771968001) and told me that it's yet to be established.

[image: Response Tweet]